# C# Windows Form DataGridView: Horizontal Scroll is not shown

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I have a weird yet simple problem: the horizontal scroll bars in DataGridView is not being shown (I use C#, Visual STudio 2010).

I have tried several permutations and combinations of the dataGridView properties but all in vain. The Vertical scrollbar appears when the number of rows is more than 6, this is good.

I have made *Layout > ScrollBars > Both*.

Here are the properties:

[image]

Apart from the ones mentioned above, in my code, the only property I change is:

> dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 200;

This is how the resulting Grid View looks like after running the code.  Where am I going wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must change the `AutoSizeColumnsMode` of your `DataGridView`.
Currently, it is set to `Fill` so the colums are resized to fit the available place.

Here is the documentation about the available modes : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewautosizecolumnsmode